# Display indicators in time toolbar from VLC media

Tags: vlc-media-player

Some time ago, i was watching an episode of a series in VLC and notice that the time toolbar has **marks** in it that indicates intro, credits,  part 1, etc.
how?
is possible with vlc or i need other program?

i try to find the episode to put screen capture, but i think i don't have it any more.

Comment: Could they be chapter markers?

Comment: Yes, most definitely chapters as suggested above. This is how the video was made, it isn't mandatory. So, what's the question exactly?

Answer (score 0):

These are [chapter](https://wiki.videolan.org/Documentation:Playback/#Chapter) markers. You can check if a video has chapters if the <kbd>Playback</kbd> -> <kbd>Chapters</kbd> menu entry has records.

As of recent version (3.0.18), there's no known way to disable them in the UI, they're a part of the timeline UI element and there's no relevant setting that mentions "chapter". The video file itself needs to have them for you to be able to use them.

If you want to make sure they didn't get disabled somehow, you can test the functionality by e.g. finding a YouTube video ([random example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pvkTC2xIbeY)) that uses chapters and downloading that with, for instance with [yt-dlp](https://github.com/yt-dlp/yt-dlp), like this:

```
yt-dlp https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pvkTC2xIbeY --embed-chapters
```